# Arithmetic expression with eval in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a problem about arithmetic expression in Perl.

I have already written the code but I couldn't fill inside of eval function.

Example:

```
>2+4

6
```

Another example:

```
>8-2*2

4
```

This is my program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

print ">";

while (<>) {   
  eval(---------);  
  print "\n>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chomp the input to remove the newline and use string eval.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
print ">" ;
while (<>) {
     chomp $_; 
     my $result = eval $_;  
     print "$result\n>"; 
}
```

Think about this: What happens when someone enters `` `rm *` `` at the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't printing the result of `eval`. The calculation is being done, but you are just throwing it away and printing another prompt.

This should do as you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

print ">" ;

while (<>) {   
  print eval, "\n>";  
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But i want to execute in this format.İt is my homework

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Your program doesn't work - you have to change something

Comment: I'm guessing it means s/he was supposed to write a function to be called where `eval()` is, not literally use eval.

Comment: @ysth: But `eval` is the *only* way to evaluate an expression stored in a string

Comment: @Borodin: `1 while s{([0-9]+)\s*([*/]|[-+](?!.*[*/]))\s*([0-9+])}{{"+"=>sub{$_[0]+$_[1]},"-"=>sub{$_[0]-$_[1]},"*"=>sub{$_[0]*$_[1]},"/"=>sub{$_[0]/$_[1]}}->{$2}->($1,$3)}e`

Comment: @ysth: Ah I see what you're saying. I was assuming a general Perl expression but I think you're right. Of course there's always `s{([\d+\-*/\s]+)}{$1}ee`

Answer (score 0):

You can just write in that way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
print ">";

while (<>) {   
  print eval("$_");  
  print "\n>"; 
}
```